# How to assign empty value to select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This works with Google Chrome and IE but not Firefox. For some reaons, Chrome and IE allow blank value to be assigned eventhough it is not part of the dropdown selection.

```
document.getElementById('dropdownid').value = "";
```

Note that I have access to jQuery but is not doing what i wanted.

```
$("#dropdownid").val("");
```

The above JQuery does not set it to a blank value because blank is not part of the dropdown options. I need to assign "" to the dropdown selectedvalue due to some third party legacy code issues.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this with?

Comment: @briosheje it is not a div. it is suppose to be dropdown (select) control

Comment: If you can copy some example `select` output from the running website, to a JSfiddle, that would help mock-up a solution and test on multiple browsers :) Use Chrome's inspect element option to copy the HTML :)

Comment: @overule, TrueBlueAussie: Sorry, read "dropdowndiv" instead of "id", my error, I'm deleting above.. Anyway, the above code works on all browsers to me.

Comment: You can't set a value to a select.  You must set the `selectedIndex` of the desired option.

Comment: @briosheje document.getElementById('dropdownid').value = ""; does not work on all browsers. I can't assign null/blank on firefox

Comment: @briansol: jQuery `.val()` *will* set it, just not to a blank entry if none exists (at least not on all browsers apparently)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes that's the issues. I am trying to set it to none

Comment: @overule: I'm using aurora instead of firefox (which should be the same, as far as I know), and it is working.

Comment: In that case, why not append an option with val = "" and set it to selected?

Comment: Is just me or this work on firefox http://jsfiddle.net/uvkv2b61/2/ ?

Comment: @AlexChar: You know what's curious? it seems that in firefox (and chrome too, to me), in jQuery 1.6.4 it DOESN'T work (http://jsfiddle.net/40gfauur/), while in jQuery 2.1 it does (like your example). Perhaps you just need to upgrade your jQuery, overule? Edit: even in jQuery 1.9.1 it isn't working, it seems that it started working since jQuery 1.10.1

Comment: setting the value to "" doesn't actually set the value to blank, it just resets the value to the default selection....

Answer (score 12):

Setting `selectedIndex` to -1 clears the selection.

```
document.getElementById('dropdownid').selectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, despite what the asker thinks, setting the value to a blank string does not actually make the value of the select a blank string. All it does is reset to the original default value...

Comment: Untested, but according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement), `selectedIndex` is read-only for `HTMLSelectElements`.

Comment: @Andy tested and working in Chrome and latest Firefox

Comment: @Andy, `selectedIndex` is not read only, `selectedOptions` is

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the `selectedIndex`. E.G:

```js
$(function(){
    $dropdown = $("#dropdownid");
    alert($dropdown.val()); //alerts "2"
    $dropdown[0].selectedIndex = -1; //or document.getElementById('dropdownid').selectedIndex = -1;
    alert($dropdown.val()) //alerts null
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdownid">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxoytdg8/

Answer (score 2):

You can try
`$(“#elementId”).val('');`
e.g.
`$(“#CountryDD”).val('');`

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you add a blank option to the select before setting it?

```
var jqDropdown = $('#dropdownid');
if (!jqDropdown.find('option[value=""]').length) {
  jqDropdown.prepend($('<option value=""></option>'));
}
jqDropdown.val("");
```

Comment: Probably `prepend` though as you would want the blank first in the list :)

Comment: Downvotes without reasons are bad. You should feel bad.

Comment: That down-vote is a little unfair. It may not be the best option, but this is a valid answer for a list with no initial blank options (aside from needing to reuse the selector and not doing `=== 0`).

Comment: For my own edification, what's wrong with `=== 0`? I get the efficiency issue, but that may not be a concern of the OP in this case. Never optimize before it's needed. :)

Comment: In jquery `!$('#dropdownid option[value=""]').length` is the "standard" way of testing whether there were "no" matches. As for efficiency, reusing a selector is just asking for maintenance errors later on so should be an initial concern for everyone :)

Comment: while these are all valid criticisms of his code, the point of this question is to solve the askers issue. code can be improved with edits afterwards.

Comment: @Mike... Review the comments please. They were just a couple of side-notes in another comment. Not a criticism. He then *asked* for my reasoning :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I agree on all points you made, just saying I usually reserve downvotes for answers that are outright wrong, not just "poor code"

Comment: @Mike: Not my down-vote, so not sure what your point is? :) I liked this answer and will file it away for possible scenarios)

Comment: Not to beg or anything, but isn't that the point of the upvote? Liking the way a question was answered?

Comment: +1: I was just waiting for, as @Mike said, "can be improved with edits afterwards" :) Which I now see you have made :> (PS you can use a self closing syntax for HTML strings in prepend e.g. `'<option value=""/>`)

Comment: I have actually run into trouble in older versions of IE using that method before. May have been clear back to IE7, but I never use self-closing in JQuery on any tags that are not meant to be so anymore. Just habit now, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried un-selecting the options in the select?

`$("#dropdownid option").prop("selected", false);`

Comment: Not tested, but this wouldn't work as there isn't a blank option. This would just set the first item in the list as the selected one.

Comment: @overule view Tetaxa's answer, it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use  `$("#dropdownid").html('');`
it makes the value null.

Comment: This is the only answer here that works when the select does not have a blank option, and in cases where such an option is not desired.  The only other way is to add the blank option, as Andy did.  Beware that this solution removes the "options" from the select entirely, but later JS/Ajax calls can repopulate the select, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**2018 jQuery 3.2.1 answer**

If you're chaining methods on a jquery selector,
`$('#selectId').slideUp(600)[0].selectedIndex = -1` appears to work (at least in Chrome) but bothers my 'stick to one syntax/framework' preference.

This also works:
`$('#selectId').slideUp(600).find('option[selected]').attr('selected', false);`

It's a bit longer, but choose the flavor you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dropdownid option[value='']").attr('selected', true)
```